# Resizing div element from the left causes the right to shift by a few px

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a box element that is resizable on all edges and corners. It seems to be working fine, except for one small thing. When I resize from the top or the left edge, the right (left edge resize) or bottom (top edge resize) will increase by a few px on each mousedown event.

I suspect that it has something to do with the width changing before the left has a chance to change, but even with a condition on the width adjustment, I get the same result.

```
if(onLeftEdge) {
   console.log('box right: ' + b.right);
   box.style.left = event.clientX + 'px';
   box.style.width = (initialClientX - event.clientX + b.width) + 'px';
}
if(onTopEdge) {
   box.style.top = event.clientY + 'px';
   box.style.height = (initialClientY - event.clientY + b.height) + 'px';
}
```

As you resize on the left, the console will show the right jumping by 1-3px.

Why doesn't the right side of the box stay put. Why does it re-adjust on mousedown?

https://codepen.io/elephantjay/pen/yrRPLM?editors=1111

Comment: can someone please tell me why this is being downvoted so that I can avoid downvotes in the future? thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a really interesting problem. You had several problems in your code, but the jump itself stems from the fact that you are using `getBoundingClientRect` to get the width and the height. On your element, you have borders and the height and width returned by the above function would have their size added. So, when you would move the left or top border for any number of pixels, it would always add 2px to the added width/height (the total width of the left+right borders or top+bottom borders respectively).

What I changed:

1. I removed the listeners added on the HTML element because they were redundant and throwing errors
2. I used `getBoundingClientRect` for the top and left properties. I extracted that to a separate function that takes the scroll into consideration, as explained [in this beautiful article](https://javascript.info/coordinates).
3. I used `getComputedStyle` for the height and width
4. I changed the resize to be relative to the element itself, not the initial X and Y coordinates
5. I added the computed `margin-top` and `margin-left` in the equation so styling the element will not affect the resizing

A working copy is shown here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/axeMge?editors=1111

Comment: setting `box-sizing: border-box` may help a lot here... :)